# CSS Find not working with Poltergeist

Tags: css, capybara, poltergeist

The following is my html source:

```
<div id="users_filter" class="btn-group no-margin pull-right nested-pull-right open">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle attach-left btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="click-dropdown" href="#"></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-filter"></ul>
</div>
```

I have the following step definition:

```
When /I click "([^\"]*)"/ do |arg1|
 find(:css, arg1).trigger('click');
end
```

And now In my feature file i do:

```
Then I click "#users_filter .dropdown-toggle"
```

But the click event does not get triggered.

I use Capybara & Poltergeist driver.

Can someone please help me understand where I'm going wrong?
Thanks
Ramya

Comment: Have you tried "find(:css, arg1).click" or "click_link(arg1)" instead of .trigger('click')?

Comment: Thanks! find(:css, arg1).click() worked!